# (C++ basic array issue) Definition/Initialization of array interfering with definition of other separate array (visual studio 2015)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-c++

If we comment out the second for-loop which is defining the char array 'croschar' the output is the char 'C' forming the shape of the letter 'C' with a length and width of five characters. When the for-loop is not commented out there is no output, i.e. the terminal hangs empty. The root of the issue might be basic but I am having a difficult time understanding why this is occurring since in my mind the arrays are functionally separated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void cbanner()
{
    const int row = 5, col = 5;
    const int raw = 5, cal = 5;

    char cchar[row][col];
    char croschar[raw][cal];

        for (int r = 0; r < row; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; ++c)
        {
            cchar[r][c] = 'C';

            if ((r > 0) && (r < (row - 1)) && (c > 0))
                cchar[r][c] = ' ';
        }
    }


    for (int rr = 0; rr < raw; ++rr)
    {
        for (int cc = 0; cc < cal; ++cc)
        {
            croschar[rr][cc] = 'p';

            if ((rr = (raw / 2)) && (cc = (cal / 2)))
                croschar[rr][cc] = '+';
        }
    }


    for (int r = 0; r < row; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; ++c)
        {
            cout << cchar[r][c];
         }
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: instead of if ((rr = (raw / 2)) && (cc = (cal / 2))),  write  if ((rr == (raw / 2)) && (cc == (cal / 2))). And of course, use a debugger.

Comment: Ah, so it is pretty basic. Apologies for using up your time.

Thanks for the links, πάντα ῥεῖ!
Highly appreciate the straightforward answer, t.m.!